# Why is my TightVNC server not displaying the LXQt desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, xorg, vnc, lxqt

I am trying to setup a vnc server on my Lubuntu 20.04 / LXQt / LightDM / Xorg / openbox machine using TightVNC.

Describing my issue upfront: When I connect from Windows machine using TightVNC (java-version) I can connect, I can see my python app running ok, that I started locally on my Lubuntu machine, but I cannot see any desktop. All gray.
My ~/.vnc/nb-lubuntu:1.log shows a lot of errors.

Here is my ~/.vnc/xstartup:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc &
exec startx &
/usr/bin/openbox &
/usr/bin/startlxqt
```

And this is my :1.log under .vnc with a bucket full of errors:

```
10/04/21 22:19:12 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
10/04/21 22:19:12 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
10/04/21 22:19:12 All Rights Reserved.
10/04/21 22:19:12 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
10/04/21 22:19:12 Desktop name 'X' (nb-lubuntu:1)
10/04/21 22:19:12 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
10/04/21 22:19:12 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
Obt-Message: XKB extension is not present on the server or too old
Obt-Message: Xinerama extension is not present on the server
Obt-Message: XRandR extension is not present on the server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server

/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Openbox-Message: Requested key "Print" does not exist on the display
Openbox-Message: Requested key "Print" does not exist on the display
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml"

** (light-locker:37818): ERROR **: 22:19:13.553: Environment variable XDG_SESSION_PATH not set. Is LightDM running?
[: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
AUDIT: Sat Apr 10 22:19:13 2021: 37728 Xtightvnc: client 13 rejected from local host
Failure: Module initialization failed
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
blueman-applet version 2.1.2 starting
There is an instance already running
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server

** (update-notifier:37905): WARNING **: 22:19:14.233: already running?
[Critical] Cannot register service 'org.lxqt.global_key_shortcuts'
[Notice] Stopped
(0x7fff1efdbfb0) Debug: New PolkitAgentListener  0x7fdccc003da0
(0x7fff1efdbfb0) Debug: Adding new listener  PolkitQt1::Agent::Listener(0x7fff1efdbfc0) for  0x7fdccc003da0
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
An instance of qlipper is already running!
(0x7ffdc9104d50) Debug: registerService failed: another service with 'org.freedesktop.Notifications' runs already
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
(0x7fffca5aa4c0) Warning: Unable to register 'org.lxqt.lxqt-powermanagement' service - is another instance of lxqt-powermanagement running?
AUDIT: Sat Apr 10 22:19:15 2021: 37728 Xtightvnc: client 18 rejected from local host
(0x7fff0fbe8860) Debug: ""
(0x7fff0fbe8860) Debug: ()
(0x7ffc852f58c0) Debug: systemd: "CanHibernate" = "challenge"
(0x7ffc852f58c0) Debug: systemd: "CanSuspend" = "challenge"
(0x7fff0fbe8860) Debug: WinIdChange 3000006 handle QWidgetWindow(0x55e8cce84850, name="LXQtPanel panel1Window") QScreen(0x55e8ccd0c680, name=":1.0")
(0x7fff0fbe8860) Debug: Systray started
(0x7fff0fbe8860) Warning: The X11 connection broke (error 2). Did the X11 server die?
mount error(16): Device or resource busy
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
RandR extension missing
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Gdk-Message: 22:22:09.825: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

(0x7ffdf5f3f750) Warning: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
(0x7fff1efdbfb0) Warning: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
(0x7ffdc9104d50) Warning: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
```

The last line mirrors my psychological condition currently.
Apparently lxqt is not starting. My desktop is 'X' as a fallback?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: possibly useful : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC

Comment: @guiverc: Thanks for the idea. TigerVNC had to be installed by manually extracting a tar.gz, renaming usr with local and mixing in the files into the existing usr/local !! Not only that: The newest package was missing a file, that I had to google and downlod manually. Why is vnc@linux in such a disarray?? Nothing really works, all tutorials are obsolete and everything is manual + no one refers to LXQT in a useful manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an alternative:

x2go.

It was easy to install it under lubuntu via

- sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
- sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession

Then install the x2go client under Windows and configure session. Pretty self-explaining and desktop perfectly visible (copy of the existing desktop, no separate session).